# jQuery data() doesn't work globally

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two functions added to jQuery native methods and which use jquery data() method to store information to retrieve latter.

Thing is I don't want to store the attribute if it has already been stored.

So I have :

```
$.fn.foo = function() {
    if(!$.hasData(this)) {
        $.data(this, 'width', this.css('width'));
        $('#test').append('foo : Added to "data"<br>');
    }
}
$.fn.bar = function() {
    if(!$.hasData(this)) {
        $.data(this, 'width', this.css('width'));
        $('#test').append('bar : Added to "data"<br>');
    }
}

$('element').foo();
$('element').bar();
```

But it outputs "Added to data" twice, instead of once. It seems that $.data() doesn't act globally at all. How should I adapt the code so that the data behave globally ?

Here's the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/e9e9vbnn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/#jQuery-data2) takes a dom element reference as its first argument, not a jQuery object. Inside the plugin method `this` will refer to the called jQuery wrapper object, not a dom element reference.

```js
$.fn.foo = function() {
  //also return this to maintain chanability
  return this.each(function() {
    if (!$.hasData(this)) {
      $.data(this, 'width', $(this).css('width'));
      $('#test').append('foo : Added to "data"<br>');
    }
  })
}
$.fn.bar = function() {
  return this.each(function() {
    if (!$.hasData(this)) {
      $.data(this, 'width', $(this).css('width'));
      $('#test').append('bar : Added to "data"<br>');
    }
  })
}

$('#element').foo();
$('#element').bar();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='test'></div>
<div id='element'></div>
```

Comment: I preffered your previous less verbose answser with just this[0], which I am using now, and it works just great ! Thanks !!